# ElectronJS - how can I have the app type for me

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I want to create an app that allows the app to type things in for me in any editor of my choosing. Is this possible in ElectronJS without native modules? Is this also possible in C++?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need typed? Is this like snippets of code? Because there are many existing programs that will allow you to define re-usable snippets of code that you can use a shortcut to input. There's also the software AutoHotKey which does a lot of automation, it really depends on your use case

Comment: It could be code, emails, professional writing etc.. I was hoping to incorporate machine learning with this so thats why I wanted this to be a separate app.